# Rename causing file access time to change

Tags: php

I am trying to move a file between directories on the same filesystem.  The difficulty I am having is that when I use `rename()` the file access time is changed for that file on the filesystem.

I tried using `shell_exec()` with mv, though for some reason when I call mv in this way it copies the file and then deletes the original which takes much longer.

Is there any way to move the file quickly without changing the access time?  Or can I change it back after calling `rename()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule the access time from a file **must** be changed when a function like `rename()`, or any other function that access a file, do it.

As for changing the access time of a file. This is only possible using the [touch](http://php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php) function, like described in the manual:

```
bool touch ( string $filename [, int $time = time() [, int $atime ]] )
```

> Attempts to set the access and modification times of the file named in the filename parameter to the value given in time. Note that the access time is always modified, regardless of the number of parameters.

As you can see the time parameter is described in the manual as:

```
touch time
```

> If time is not supplied, the current system time is used.

And here is an example from the same page of setting the access time one hour back from a file:

```
<?php
    // This is the touch time, we'll set it to one hour in the past.
    $time = time() - 3600;

    // Touch the file
    if (!touch('some_file.txt', $time)) {
        echo 'Whoops, something went wrong...';
    } else {
        echo 'Touched file with success';
    }
?>
```

However, be aware that the touch function, as described, **attempts** to change the file. If you have no permission for example the function will return `false`. (and won't change the file time)

Cheers

Comment: Thank you for your help, it would seem as if rename is still taking a while to copy the file so Ill stick to the shell_exec option.  Do you know of any way to move the file just updating the filesystem without it seemingly needing to copy/delete the file?

Comment: In some filesystems all that is need to move a file like /foo/bar/file.extension to /foo/file.extension is to rename the file to /foo/file.extension. So this is a way of moving without copying. But there's no way of moving a file without deleting it after. (BTW, this is another question)

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily store the access time of the file using [`fileatime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileatime.php) and modify it using [`touch`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php).

```
$filename = 'somefile.txt';
$original_timestamp = fileatime($filename);
// .. modify file here ..
touch($filename, $original_timestamp);
```